# Is there a better way to set sys.path.append in python project?

Tags: python, python-import

I have a simple python project with the following directory structure:

```
sample-project/
main/
    config/
        config.yaml
    docker/
        Dockerfile
    tests/
        __init__.py
        sometests.py
    config.py
    run.py
    __init__.py
requirements.txt
README.rst
```

In the **config.py** file, I have:

```
import yaml


class Config:

def __init__(self):
    with open("config/config.yaml", 'r') as ymlfile:
        cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)

        self.host = cfg["mysql"]["host"]
        self.database = cfg["mysql"]["database"]
        self.user = cfg["mysql"]["user"]
        self.password = cfg["mysql"]["password"]


my_config = Config()
```

In the **run.py** file, I have an import statement as follows:

```
from main.config import my_config
```

when I run using command line: **python3.5 run.py**, I get the error:

> from main.config import my_config
>
> ImportError: No module named 'main'

But when I add this in run.py imports it works:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/tomas/sample-project/')
```

Is there any better way to make it work rather than give absolute path or any other way? Please give some example :)

Comment: You could append the part relative using `sys.path.append('..')`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, never ever touch `sys.path` from within your program.

Since `main/` (not the best name) contains an `__init__.py`, we'll consider it a package, so let's [make it runnable as one](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/__main__.html#module-__main__). This way imports will be considered correctly.

Add `main/__main__.py` with e.g.

```
from main.run import run

if __name__ == "__main__":
   run()
```

Then run your app with

```
python -m main
```

instead of

```
python main/main.py
```

Comment: I don't think it works what you said or I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: /usr/bin/python3.5: No module named main

Comment: Are you running that from the directory where `main/` is?

Comment: Yep, running from '/home/tomas/sample-project/' - next directory is main..
even cd into main and tried but same error.

Answer (score 0):

when mentioning below
from main.config import my_config

keep dir path also 
eg:
from sample-project/main.config import my_config

assuming you are executing from /home/tomas

Answer (score 0):

Although I share AKX's sentiment that editing your path is something to avoid I would generally suggest the following method:

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname
abs_dir = dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(abs_dir)
```

The `__file__` variable provides access to the location of the file in which it is accessed. This allows you to get an absolute path to any file in your project.